# How to pass a Selector in a mixin-VUE

Tags: javascript, vue.js, mixins

I'm trying to make a Mixin with which I'd like to calculate the offsetWidth of an element.

This is my Mixin:

```
export const boxWidth = (selector) => ({
  mounted() {
    selector.addEventListener(
      'resize',
    this.setBoxWidth
  );
},
methods: {
  setBoxWidth(e) {
   let box = e.target;
   this.myBoxWidth =  box.offsetWidth;
   console.log(this.myBoxWidth);
  }
}
})
```

I trying to call this in a component:

```
<template>
  <div
    ref="visuraBox"
    class="container"
  >
    <div class="field">
      <label class="label">Name</label>
      <div class="control">
        <input
          class="input"
          type="text"
          placeholder="e.g Alex Smith"
        >
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field ">
      <label class="label">Name</label>
      <div class="control">
        <input
          class="input"
          type="text"
          placeholder="e.g Alex Smith"
        >
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { boxWidth } from '../mixins/boxWidth'

export default {
  name: 'VisuraCatForm',
  mixins: [boxWidth(this.$refs.visuraBox)],
  data() {
    return {
      myBoxWidth: 0
    }
  },
  created() {
    const myBox = this.$refs.visuraBox
    this.myBoxWidth = myBox.offsetWidth;
  }
}
</script>

<style lang='scss' scoped>
@import '@/assets/design/components/_form.scss';
</style>
```

Obviously in this way the ref doesen't exist yet, so my answer is:
How can i pass a selector inside a mixin?
(P.S. I prefer to don't declare the mixin globally)

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there...

I suggest you add a method to your mixin that handles what you already have within the mounted hook of the mixin:

```
listenForResize(selector) {
    selector.addEventListener('resize', this.setBoxWidth);
}
```

Then you can call this new method from the mounted hook of your original component.